It (so) happened that she was out when we called

(1) It happened that she was out when we called.
(OALD)
(2) It so happened that she was out when we called.

[Q1] Is there any difference in meaning or connotation between these two sentences?
[Q2] Do (1) and (2) sound natural in ordinary conversation? In ordinary conversation, I would probably say:

(3) She happened to be out when we called. (OALD)


I don't find the first perfectly idiomatic with the it-cleft. This would be idiomatic:

She happened to be out when we called.

as would this:

It happened to be the case that she was out when we called.

and this:

It so happened (that) she was out when we called.

But the it-cleft

It happened she was out when we called.

when recast without the cleft:

(That) she was out when we called happened.

sounds very odd, ungrammatical, whereas

That she was out when we called happened to be the case.

sounds grammatical, though a tad clunky. But it wants a context where one is emphasizing that her being out when we called was indeed the fact, perhaps to a doubter who believes that to be unlikely. "She's always in. She never leaves the house."
Why?  I think "raw" or "bare" happened (i.e. as distinct from the modified "so happened") needs a complement other than a declarative content-clause.

Thank you, TimR. In It happened to be the case that she was out when we called, is "It" a dummy it?

Some people call "it" in that cleft construction "dummy it".

Really? I find It happened to be the case that she was out when we called. extremely clunky.

It would be very clunky if it were it used to state the initial fact. But when rebutting someone's doubt ("Really? She's always home. She never leaves the house."  *Well, it happens to be the case that she was out when we called.")  no so much.

Does It so happened that she was out when we called sound natural in casual conversation?

Yes, it indicates that you called expecting her to be there but she wasn't.  It is often used to clarify things for the listener. Consider this conversation: "A: We called her yesterday. -- B:  Oh, what did she have to say?   A: It so happened, she was out when we called."

Adding "so" just adds emphasis to the suggestion of coincidence.
Two things happened - you called, she wasn't there. There's no suggestion she went out to avoid you, or that you called because you knew she wasn't there. It's an unfortunate coincidence.
